# Why am I getting an error when calling a webservice function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am coding a C# web api 2 webservice and would like some help to get a single item from a request to a webservice.

Here is the web service controller class code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class ItemsWebApiController : ApiController
```

Here is the web service function:

```
// GET: api/Getitem/1
[Route("Getitem")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(Item))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetItem(int id)
{
    Item item = await db.items.FindAsync(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(item);
}
```

Here is the uri to the IIS website:

http://localhost/thephase

Here is the uri that I am accessing:

http://localhost/thephase/api/Getitem/1

Here is the error that is being displayed in the browser:

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost/thephase/api/GetItem/1'.","MessageDetail":"No type
>   was found that matches the controller named 'GetItem'."}

Here is the `WebApiConfig` code:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
}
```

The error states that the controller is named `'GetItem'`, and this is incorrect. Hence I am thinking that the problem is in the `WebApiConfig` route code.

If I remove the `int id` from the function, then the function is called correctly.

Here is the same function with no parameter:

```
// GET: api/Getitemnoparameter
[Route("Getitemnoparameter")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(Item))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetItem()
{
    Item item = await db.items.FindAsync(1);
    if (item == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(item);
}
```

The following uri accesses the function correctly:

http://localhost/thephase/api/Getitemnoparameter

So the problem has something to do with the `int` parameter.

Can someone please help me to get access the `GetItem` function with a parameter?

Comment: Is it because the route is case sensitive (`Getitem` versus `GetItem`)?

Comment: I have edited the uri to be Getitem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using Attribute Routing you also need to specify the parameter for it to work.

Check this tutorial out for a better understanding.

[Route Prefixes](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes)

```
[Route("Getitem/{id:int}")]
```

Comment: Thank you. The code is now being accessed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `Id` is an `int`. `int` is a value type. Value types cannot be null. You set the parameter to `RouteParameter.Optional`, but if it's optional, it must be able to be assigned null.

Solution: Use a nullable int

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetItem(int? id)
```